# Does the Android Youtube API support the gyroscope when embedding 360 degree videos?

Tags: android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With the YouTube Android app, 360 degree videos support using the gyroscope to pan around the video, which is amazing. Is this possible when using the YouTubeStandalonePlayer or YouTubePlayerView in an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched the online documentation for YouTubeStandalonePlayer and YouTubePlayerView, and can't find any indication that this is currently possible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30732653/3549440) similar question.